# Are cluster and fork same?

Tags: node.js, process, cluster-computing

I have read a lot of node.js system, and I am a little bit confused.

I have a 4 core CPU.

In node.js,
To create a new thread I should do

```
var child = require('child_process').fork('child.js');
child.on("message", function(){});
```

- This will run the code on new thread under CPU #0.
- Each new thread in that way will be created on CPU #0, until the memory will be full.
- To use CPU #1 and #2 and #3, I need to use `cluster`, right?
- So I can use both, `fork` and `cluster` right?
- If `cluster` use `fork` so basically it createS only 4 threads? Is that right?
- **Is `process.id` a real process id, not thread? not thread id?**

So my picture is that:

```
cpu #0:
  thread #0
  thread #1
  thread #2
  thread #3
cpu #1
  thread #0
  thread #1
  thread #2
  thread #3
so on..
```

Am I correct?
Does cluster create only threads?

Answer (score 2):

> This is will run the code on new thread under cpu #0.

Wrong. The operating system will determine which core it runs on (and it may not always stay on the same core). That's totally an OS thing. And keep in mind the OS is handling/allocating **all** threads, not just the node.js threads.

As to the difference between `child_process.fork` and `cluster`... From the [node.js cluster documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works):

> The worker processes are spawned using the child_process.fork()
>   method, so that they can communicate with the parent via IPC and pass
>   server handles back and forth.

So cluster is actually **using** `child_process.fork` to start with.

But it adds additional functionality on top of this: for example if you are running an http server, cluster can "distribute incoming connections" across the child processes. So if you're not using this for something with incoming connections that need to be distributed, you probably don't need `cluster`.